Webview API in VS Code: Local Video Playback Works, but YouTube Video Doesn't Play
I'm developing a VS Code extension using the Webview API and am trying to implement video playback. I was able to play local video files (e.g., MP4) without any issues, but I’m having trouble playing embedded YouTube videos.

Question: While local videos work fine, YouTube videos embedded within the webview do not play. The YouTube iframe loads, but the
video doesn't start when I click play.
What I’ve Tried: I’ve embedded the YouTube video using an iframe in the webview’s HTML. There are no errors in the console, but the
video controls are unresponsive.
Additional Details: I’m using the latest version of VS Code. The webview is set up with default settings, and I’ve ensured that the
correct permissions are in place for the webview.

Is there a known limitation or workaround for playing YouTube videos in a VS Code webview? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

(1) What is a local file in this question? Is it a file put in same folder as the app? Is it a file somewhere else on the hard drive (eg: in "c:\My Documents" folder)? Or maybe your local means localhost? Knowing how might give others a clue towards an answer for you. (2) Does turning autoplay on (in the iframe embed options) make the Youtube video play, at least?

@VC.One Local File Definition: In my case, a local file refers to video files stored directly on my computer’s hard drive, not necessarily within the same folder as the app. For testing, I used MP4 files located in various directories on my system, such as "C:\My Videos". These files play correctly when embedded in the webview using a standard HTML5 video element.

YouTube Video and Autoplay: I’ve attempted to enable autoplay in the YouTube iframe embed options, but the video still doesn’t play. The iframe loads correctly, displaying the player UI with all controls visible. However, when I click the play button, nothing happens—the video simply doesn’t start. I’ve also tried adjusting other parameters, such as allowfullscreen and allow="autoplay", but these changes did not resolve the issue.
